# SwiftUI Preview Update Failed with Archiving Error

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widget

I am currently learning iOS Widgets, and I have encountered this strange error when I try to preview my widget. Here is what the Diagnostics says:

```
== PREVIEW UPDATE ERROR:

    PotentialCrashError: Update failed
    
    ZohoMailWidgetTest may have crashed. Check ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports for any crash logs from your application.
    
    ==================================
    
    |  RemoteHumanReadableError
    |  
    |  ArchivingError: failedToEncode(types: [SwiftUI.(unknown context at $107d0ac9c).ListRepresentable<SwiftUI.CollectionViewListDataSource<Swift.Never>, SwiftUI.SelectionManagerBox<Swift.Never>>, SwiftUI.(unknown context at $107d0ac9c).ListRepresentable<SwiftUI.CollectionViewListDataSource<Swift.Never>, SwiftUI.SelectionManagerBox<Swift.Never>>])
```

The relevant body of my code looks like this:

```swift
struct MailWidgetTestWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                VStack {
                    Image(systemName: "envelope")
                    Text("494")
                }
                
                Image(systemName: "pencil.circle.fill")
                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
            }
            
            List {
                MailWidgetListCellView()
                MailWidgetListCellView()
                MailWidgetListCellView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MailWidgetListCellView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("Team Spark")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    Text("12:15 PM")
                        .font(.caption)
                    
                }
                
                Text("Use Spark to reclaim your focus")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            }
            
            Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")
                .font(.title)
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
    }
}
```

This error does not pop up when I change my `List` into a `VStack` instead, like this:

```swift
struct MailWidgetTestWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                VStack {
                    Image(systemName: "envelope")
                    Text("494")
                }
                
                Image(systemName: "pencil.circle.fill")
                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
            }
            
            VStack { //no errors now
                MailWidgetListCellView()
                MailWidgetListCellView()
                MailWidgetListCellView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am unable to find any solution to this problem anywhere else. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: What version of iOS and Xcode are you running the preview on? This isn't crashing for me on Xcode 15.2.0 on a 17.2 Preview

Comment: @BrandonStillitano I am using 15.2.0 with iOS 15 Pro (17.0) simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use any scrollable elements in Widgets because they don't support scrolling. This behavior was mentioned in [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10028/).